# npm packages.json: devDependencies vs global installation

Tags: programming-practices, node.js

I'm new Node.js development and I have a question about best practices when writing `package.json` files.

From my understanding, you have to list all devependences that you need to execute your app under `"dependencies"` in the `package.json` file. All your extra dependences that are required to run your test (or your build process) have to be listed in `"devDependencies"`.

But what about tools that you additionally use, but which are not necessarily required by every developer. Take the `node-inspector` package as an example, which I installed globally on my machine but did not add to the `package.json` file.

Is that a good practice, or would you recommend to also file those packages as `"devDependencies"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`devDependencies` are packages you *need* in order to work on your project. Testing frameworks used in the project, mock APIs, CSS preprocessors (if you don't ship a compiled version) fit here.

`node-inspector` is not needed for you to run tests and make changes to parts of your code, so  it should not be included in the package. Other users might use different debuggers.